# ReferenceError: ajaxfunction is not defined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been unable to get an ajax script to run for some time.

Basically, I need the user to select an option from one drop down box, then, based on what's selected, the second drop down box with populate accordingly based on a MySQL query.

My Script looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('select [name="front-size"]').change(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../functions/process.php',
            type:'get',
            data:{'value' : $(this).val()}, 
            dataType:"html",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#sub").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

My initial drop down box is populated by a MySQL query like so

```
<select name="front-size" onchange="ajaxfunction(this.value)">
     <?php
    $door_size = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT door_size FROM doors WHERE door_model = '".$_SESSION['front_door']."'");
    $door_size->execute();
    while($row = $door_size->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $size = $row['door_size'];
        echo '<option value="'.$size.'">'.$size.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

The second drop down box is empty

```
<select name="front-finish" id="sub" onchange="ajaxfunction(this.value)">
</select>
```

And process.php should do the next query based on what was previously selected (this works on its own)

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include ('config.php');

    $parent = $_GET['parent'];

    $update_option = $db->prepare("SELECT door_finish FROM doors WHERE door_model = '".$_SESSION['front_door']."' AND door_size = '".$parent."'");
    $update_option->execute();
    while($row = $update_option->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $door_finishes = $row['door_finish'];
        echo '<option value="'.$door_finishes.'">'.$door_finishes.'</option>';

    }
?>
```

In Firebug, when I select my first drop down menu, this error is shown and I've been unable to solve it.

```
ReferenceError: ajaxfunction is not defined

ajaxfunction(this.value)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling ajaxfunction but you haven't defined it anywhere in the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('select [name="front-size"]').change(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../functions/process.php',
            type:'get',
            data:{'value' : $(this).val()}, 
            dataType:"html",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#sub").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
    });
function ajaxFunction(stuff){
//do ajax stuff here will fix the error 
}
</script>
```

On a broader note, why are you calling that inline in your html (`onchange=ajaxfunction(this.value)`) when the same thing can be accomplished in your ready function?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
$('select[name="first"]').change(function(){
//do stuff
});
$('select[name="second"]').change(function(){
//do other stuff
});
})
</script>
```

would be better

EDIT: check this jsfiddle for a working example http://jsfiddle.net/WF8CV/

Comment: But haven't I already added my ajax stuff under $.ajax? I've tried adding ajaxfunction to the $('select [name="front-size"]').change(function () line after function but that doesn't work.

Comment: I've also tried to add it to the first function but that doesn't work either.

Comment: at least one problem as well is that you're using an invalid selector "select [name='front-size']" doesn't work because you've got a space between the element and the [name=]

Comment: Right, I'm still confused about the actual ajaxfunction function though. I though that the $,ajax section was the ajax stuff so what do I need to do under function ajaxfunction(stuff){}??

Comment: also just added a JS fiddle to demonstrate this.  $.ajax does not equal ajaxfunction().  you have to explicitly name your function and call it on some action OR (as you've done) define an anonymous function to handle the your change event in your jquery ready function

Comment: your problem isn't (necessarily) the call to $.ajax.  its that your not calling it properly.  calling ajaxfunction doesn't call $.ajax.  you've already bound an anonymous function to your change event so the inline call to ajaxfunction actually doesn't do anything but throw an error because you haven't defined it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26408/discussion-between-brad-and-michael-n)