# referenceerror $ is not defined ajax for getting xml

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery in my head tag for my offical website. It doesn't work and comes up with the referenceerror $ is not defined $.ajax error. I tried these solutions(down below), but it doesn't solve my problem. The first one di

Solutions Tried:

1.Query needs to be the first script you import. The first script on your page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/test/wp-content/themes/child/script/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
```

2.[ReferenceError: ajaxfunction is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488704/referenceerror-ajaxfunction-is-not-defined)
I am calling my function as the first function to be called.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
XMLLIST = {
      xml: 'slideshow.xml?' + Math.random(0,1),
      display: '10',
      random: false,
      appentTo: '#slideshow',

      int: function () {
                $.ajax({
                        type:"GET",
                        url:"slideshow.xml",
                             dataType:"xml",
                             sucess: XMLLIST.parseXML,
                }); 
      },

      parseXML: function (xml) {
                var data=$('slideInfo', xml).get();
                var list = data;
                var i = 1;
                          $(list).each(function() {
                          XMLLIST.insertHTML($(this));
                          if( i == XMLLIST.display) return false;
                          i++;
                          });
     },


insertHTML: function (slide) {
            var title = slide.find('title').text();
            var image = slide.find('image').text();
            var alternate = slide.find('alt').text();
            var disclaimer = slide.find('disclaimer').text();
            var diet = slide.find('diet').text();
            var sciencename = slide.find('sciencename').text();
            var facts = slide.find('facts').text();
            var rangehabitat = slide.find('rangehabitat').text();
            var html;

            html = '<div class="slideInfo">';
            html += '<img scr="' + image + '" alt="' + alternate + '"id ="slideImage" />';
            html += '<p id="altTag>"' + alternate + '"</p>"';
            html += '<p id="Animaldisclaimer">"' + disclaimer + '"</p>';
            html += '<p id="scienceName">"' + sciencename + '"</p>'; 
            html += '<p id="RH">"' + rangehabitat + '"</p>';
            html += '<p id="animalFacts">"' + facts + '"</p>';

            $(html).appendTo(XMLLIST.appentTo);
},
}

XMLLIST.int();
```

Answer (score 2):

`$` is undefined because you're not loading jQuery. You're loading a jQuery plugin, but not jQuery itself. Loading jQuery should get you a little farther, e.g.:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That goes before any `<script>` tags that load your plugins or other jQuery scripts.

At least that's all I can guess from the code you posted. If you post a link to a complete test page it would be possible to give more specific advice.

Comment: I am new to jquery so how would I go about that? Would I use a specific script tag to link it?

Comment: If you're new to this it would be good to find some working examples and fiddle around with those. It's easier to take a working page and turn it into a different working page, one little step at a time, than it is to get everything right at once.

Comment: I am really glad you mentioned that jquery goes before the other tags.  That is easy to overlook